# ios change notifications for app from inside app

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a "settings" tab inside my app that asks the user if they want to "receive notifications when the app is closed?"

Normally a user has to do this in the IOS5 notifications center in the general tab. Can I modify those settings for my own app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't directly modify settings in your app.

The best you can do is to use an URL scheme to take the user directly to the notification settings for your app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=Mail"]];
```

(Replace "Mail" with the bundle display name of your app.)

Answer (score 0):

you can stop your server from sending push messages to apple. but you cannot trigger the system settings.